# Navigate between screens with transition in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 screens and I want to navigate between them with a custom transition (using a library named `flutter_spinkit`).
How can I go from Page1 to Page2 showing my custom loading screen for 2-3 seconds ?
Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Page1(),
  ));
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Go!'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Route _createRoute() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    // transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime, child) {
      child = Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple[700],
        body: Center(
          child: SpinKitFadingCube(
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 100.0,
          ),
        ),
      );

      return ScaleTransition(
        scale: animation,
        child: child,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
      );
    },
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime) => Page2(),
  );
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Page 2'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got your point. Maybe you just need to change the `transitionsBuilder` to check the animation is complete or not. I also change the name of `SpinKitFadingCube` because it should not replace the original child Widget.

```
  transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime, child) {
    final loading= Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple[700],
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitFadingCube(
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 100.0,
        ),
      ),
    );

    if(animation.isCompleted){
      return child;
    }else{
      return loading;
    }
  },
```

Comment: I don't think this is the fix to my issue. On Page1 I have a button and when I click it I wanna go on Page2 but with a transition of 2 seconds. And for that transition I want to use an animation from `flutter_spinkit` library.

Comment: flutter spinkit is a loader/progressbar. You want transition or a loader?

Comment: I didn't notice the PageRouteBuilder at the first time. The `transitionsBuilder` usually use for two page transition (usually define how the second page come in like scale or slide). If you don't mine the page loaded immediately, you can just return the page you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Animate when going from One Screen to Another Screen**

Your `onPressed` or `onTap` method:

```
InkWell(
 onTap: () {
   Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute());
 },
)
```

and then inside your `_createRoute` method

```
Route _createRoute() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 2), //You can change the time here
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => SecondScreen(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      var begin = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
      var end = Offset.zero;
      var curve = Curves.easeInCirc;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

with `Duration(seconds: 2)` you can change the time from `microsecond`, `seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`

There are many other Curves animations like `Curves.easeInCirc`, which can be found [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves-class.html)

### OR

If you want to use `Flutter_Spinkit` for showing a type of Animated Loading Indicator than this is how it is done!

Add Dependency:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.2"
```

Then import it in your screen:

```
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
```

and then you can use the `Flutter Spinkit Loader` where it is required like:

```
final spinkit = SpinKitFadingCircle(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: index.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: And how can I show this animation when I navigate from Screen1 to Screen2 ?

Comment: this is copy paste from Flutter website. What I don't know how to do is to display that Flutter Spinkit Animation for 2 seconds when I navigate from Screen1 to Screen2. How can you edit your function `_createRoute` to use that Spinkit animation instead of that SlideTransition ?